# gulp: node cannot find module 'vscode'

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension for VS Code and also writing some tests against my objects used by that extension.  Those tests run successfully from within VS Code.  However, I also want them to run as a part of my CI build and I do that via gulp.  I have a gulp task that uses "gulp mocha" to run the tests.  Those tests will run successfully via gulp until I bring in a class that, anywhere in it's transitive closure of module references, pulls in 'vscode'.

My gulp output is below:

```
[13:29:03] Starting 'test'...
[13:29:03] { [Error: Cannot find module 'vscode']
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  name: 'Error',
  message: 'Cannot find module \'vscode\'',
  stack: 'Error: Cannot find module \'vscode\'\n    at
Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)\n    at
Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)\n    at Module.require
(module.js:353:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)\n    at 
Object.<anonymous> (C:\\vsts-vscode\\out\\src\\helpers\\settings.js:6:18)\n  
at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)\n    at
Object.Module._extensions..js    
(module.js:404:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)\n    at
Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)\n    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)',
showStack: true,
showProperties: true,
plugin: 'gulp-mocha' }
[13:29:03] 'test' errored after 212 ms
[13:29:03] Error in plugin 'gulp-mocha'
Message:
    Cannot find module 'vscode'
Details:
    code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
Stack:
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (**C:\vsts-vscode\out\src\helpers\settings.js:6:18**)
    at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:404:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

In the call stack, there's a reference to **src\helpers\settings.js:6:18**.  At that location is this statement:

```
const vscode_1 = require("vscode");
```

In my typescript source, that is:

```
import { workspace } from "vscode";
```

If I simply remove the import statement that brings in the namespace I use within settings.js, the tests go back to running successfully.

After going through the documentation regarding node.js module resolution (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), I can understand why I get MODULE_NOT_FOUND.  Since "vscode" isn't a core module and isn't a relative reference (".", "/", "../"), node will look for the package.json file.  Assuming it finds it (procmon tells me it does), it looks for a "main" field.  I'm guessing that, at this point, it doesn't find the "main" field and fails the resolution.

Presumably, when running the tests in VS Code (which works fine), the resolution also includes locating the typings file (http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) and is thus successful.

What I can't figure out is what I might do to resolve the reference to "vscode" when I run tests via gulp.

Any thoughts?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Doing what I was attempting isn't expected to work (and won't)... [see here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6586).  Basically, 'unit tests' can't reference the 'vscode' module (even transitively) or they'll fail like this.  As the link suggests, if you're referencing 'vscode' then you'll need VS Code installed on the box to run the test.  More info is in that link above.